# How do access a value from Context.Consumer with recompose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im passing some data with React Context API
and I try to access it from inside a recompose methods

In what way do you access `Consumer's` data with recompose?

```
import React from "react";
import { MyContext } from "./index";
import { fromRenderProps, withProps, compose } from "recompose";

const enhance = compose(
    /**
     * @todo add 'Mr.' to each name
     */
    withProps(/** How do I get "names" from Consumer here? */)
);

const GrandChild = props => {
    return (
        <MyContext.Consumer>
            {names => {
                console.log(names)
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h2>GrandChild</h2>
                        {names.map((name, index) => (<li key={index}>{name}</li>))}
                    </div>
                );
            }}
        </MyContext.Consumer>
    );
};

export default enhance(GrandChild);
```

**live code:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/k0xm2vlw8r

Comment: Please show in your sandbox an example of what you want to do with `names` within the `compose` call and turn it into an example that actually uses GrandChild. It's fine if it errors due to not having `names`, but get it otherwise working. Right now your sandbox doesn't actually define `MyContext` anywhere or try to use GrandChild, so it can't be used to actually verify a proposed solution.

Comment: @RyanCogswell
Ohh sorry I've add a wrong link accidently,
https://codesandbox.io/s/k0xm2vlw8r 

I want to be able to use the value I pass with context inside recompose methods, and I'm not sure what the right method for doing this?

Comment: It would be helpful to see at least a simple example of something you would actually use that context for within the recompose methods so that I know the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than just knowing the shape of the solution you are trying to use.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I have a big chain of nested components, I want to pass some data from parent into grand grand grand child. I want to user Context API for this.
and inside the last nested child pass some data I saved in the context.
the value i get and pass from the parent is has this shape `{name: string, path: string}`, I want to reshape the value to a different shape. in my case its `{path: name}[]` so I want to do the props transformation with `withProps`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell
... in order of reshaping my data i need to be able to access it inside withProps under a props, so I need to find a way to pass the value i pass with context inside 1 of the compose methods.  Hope this made it clearer

Comment: Yes that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve this:

`GrandChild.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { MyContext } from "./index";
import { withProps, compose } from "recompose";

const enhance = compose(
  withProps(({ names }) => ({ reshapedNames: ["this first", ...names] }))
);

const GrandChild = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>GrandChild</h2>
      {props.reshapedNames.map((name, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{name}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
const EnhancedGrandChild = enhance(GrandChild);
const EnhancedGrandChildWithContext = props => {
  return (
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      {names => <EnhancedGrandChild names={names} {...props} />}
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  );
};
export default EnhancedGrandChildWithContext;
```

Just adds a separate layer to provide the context.

Here's the CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit 8z18469pj2]